# synchronize data from external list and SPList

Tags: bcs, timer-jobs

How do we synchronize data from an external list (BCS) into a custom SharePoint list? I have tried using a timer job, but it did not help. Any ideas?

Comment: Why did the timer job not help?  I've done that in the past in an environment that did not have the BDC or BCS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SPTimer job and BCS External list](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/23100/sptimer-job-and-bcs-external-list)

Answer (score 1):

1. Create an External Content Type (using sharepoint designer)
2. go to CA and set up BCS permissions (may want to secure store)
3. If it's one time load into SP list then create a list based on External list (your bcs connection should show up)
4. You can then use powershell to populate your target SP list.

Comment: This would be only a one time deal. I would like to keep the data synchronized items between external and SP list.

Comment: I have been trying to do something similar to Step 4, and get stuck with some extra issues that seem to arise when you try to access an *external* list via PowerShell. If you (Mary Rivers) have done step 4, an example would be useful.

Comment: Where is the data in the external list coming from and why do you want to duplicate it? What do you mean by sync? Is this a purge then re-import method or is the intention to update existing data and add new?